# Problems with SingleChildScrollView - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to leave a container fixed and the other part of the screen that can do some scrolling is there a possibility to replicate not the screen, only these two events?
[image]

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(


          child: Container(color: Colors.blue,height: 1000,width: double.infinity,))
       /*  body(context, screenWidth, screenHeight),
        bottmtop(context), */
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: use CustomScrollview with SliverAppBar as red header and SliverFillRemaining as you blue container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this exmaple as it.
If You want to user list than use SliverList in place of SliverFillRemaining;

```
 class HeadState extends State<Head> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: []),
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: screenHeight / 4,
                flexibleSpace: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: Container(
                  height: screenHeight - screenHeight / 4,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```